# Returning body text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, email, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape HTML tags off of something that was returned using ExchangeLib. What I have so far is this:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

credentials = Credentials('myemail@notreal.com', 'topSecret')
account = Account('myemail@notreal.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item.unique_body, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

As is, this will use exchangeLib to grab the first email from my inbox via Exchange, and print specifically the `unique_body` which contains the body text of the email. Here is a sample of the output from `print(soup)`:

```
<html><body><div>
<div><span lang="en-US">
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">Hey John,</span></font></div>
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;"> </span></font></div>
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">Here is a test email</span></font></div>
</span></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

My end goal is to have it print:

```
Hey John,
Here is a test email
```

From what I'm reading on BeautifulSoup documentation, the process of scraping falls between my "`Soup ="` line and the final `print` line.

My issue is that in order to run the scraping portion of BeautifulSoup, it requires a class and h1 tags such as: `name_box = soup.find(‘h1’, attrs={‘class’: ‘name’})`, however from what I currently have, I have none of this.

As someone who is new to Python, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `Find_all` to get all the `font` tag value and then iterate.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""<html><body><div>
<div><span lang="en-US">
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">Hey John,</span></font></div>
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;"> </span></font></div>
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">Here is a test email</span></font></div>
</span></div>
</div>
</body></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for span in soup.find_all('font'):
      print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
Hey John,

Here is a test email
```

Comment: This worked! Output was exactly how you said it would be. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to print the font tag content. You can use `select` method and pass it type selector for the element of `font`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html><body><div>
<div><span lang="en-US">
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">Hey John,</span></font></div>
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;"> </span></font></div>
<div style="margin:0;"><font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">Here is a test email</span></font></div>
</span></div>
</div>
</body></html>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

textStuff = [item.text for item in soup.select('font') if item.text != ' ']
print(textStuff)
```

Comment: Tried it, had to change `bs(html, 'lxml')` to `BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')`. My new output is:

`['Hey John,', '\xa0', 'Here is a test email']`

So much better, but still have to do some slight fixes

Comment: I aliased BeautifulSoup as bs in the import statement which is why it was different.

Comment: I don't get the '\xa0' value so I guess there may be something different from what you are showing?  What are these remaining fixes? At present I seem to get the expected result. select method is also fast.

Comment: you can always remove the unicode with .replace('\xa0', ' ') but I still don't know how you are getting that as mine prints perfectly. Do you have some difference in language settings perhaps?